# Depth traversal Orientdb

Tags: orientdb, traversal, depth

How can I get depth traversal of  a graph in Orientdb .
Using the documentation here is what I tried , yet when I run in I get an error here is the query .

```
EXPLAIN SELECT FROM (TRAVERSE any("Edge1") FROM P_H WHILE $depth <= 3) WHERE p ='SP00000000001';
```

The goal is the get the equivalent of this Neo4j Query :

```
MATCH (n:Node{NodeID:"SP00000000001"})-[:Edge1*1..3]-(d) RETURN Distinct d, n
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing is using a MATCH statement: http://orientdb.com/docs/2.2.x/SQL-Match.html

```
 MATCH
   {class:Node, as:n, where:(NodeID = "SP00000000001") -EdgeClass- {as:d, while:($depth < 3), where: ($matched.n != $currentMatch)} }
 RETURN d, n
```

Or `RETURN $elements` if you want the vertices expanded

Comment: but it is so slow ? is that a normal behaviour?

Comment: How many edges does the left node have? I just updated the answer with an additional condition that should speed up the query

Comment: Why is orientdb showing slow behaviour  for depth 3 ?

Comment: The speed depends mainly on how many vertices/edges you are traversing. If your graph has a span of 1000, depth 3 means traversing 1billion edges

Comment: In test performances we observe that OrientDB is faster than neo4j , yet I'm getting the opposite result, neo4j is presented to be faster , is that  normal